# Is there any way/support to handle DCC in Malaysia?

Tags: android, paypal, credit-card

I am trying to use pay-pal mobile SDK for an android app. pay-pal payment works fine but when I try Direct Credit Card, I receive system_error_bad_currency.

Comment: Are you trying to use DCC in Malaysian ringgit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Malaysian ringitt is not supported for direct credit card payments. It is only suppoted for payments using paypal balance

You need to bill your product using a different currency.

> Malaysian Ringgit 
>   Note: This currency is supported as a payment currency and a currency balance for in-country PayPal accounts only.
>
> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes